# ng-model not working with kendo -editor textarea

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I am having a `kendo-editor textarea`

```
<textarea name="CallNotes" id="CallNotes" class="txtarea1" kendo-editor k-encoded="false" 
      ng-model="Models.SalesCallBookingModel.CallNotes"
      ng-required="true"
      k-ng-disabled="Variables.viewOnly"
      k-tools="[
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'underline',
            'strikethrough',
            'foreColor',
            'backColor'
              ]"></textarea>
```

In the java script , I am assigning the value to the model like this

```
$scope.Models.SalesCallBookingModel.CallNotes = "Hi";
```

However, I can't see the value `"hi"` on the view. I even tried by replacing `ng-model` with `k-ng-model`. Just to be sure I removed `kendo-editor` from HTML and it worked perfectly fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to initialize the Models and SalesCallBookingModel properties before you can assign value to CallNotes.

Also you need k-ng-model, because otherwise the Kedno editor will not be aware of changes you do in the controller. Only Angular will be notified for changes in the editor.

Here is your code working:

http://dojo.telerik.com/iGiRi